# Avoid Overwriting in file.copy in R

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Can I avoid overwriting in case of file.copy() in Shiny in R. I know how to save file in a particular folder. But my code is overwriting uploaded file every case. I want that copied file should be saved with different sames. Can I do this in R? If yes, then how? I am posting my code. But my effort is just uploading files with same name i.e. "0.png". Please suggest the way of uploading files with different names. Thank you

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent (input$uploaded_file, {
    file.copy(input$uploaded_file$datapath, "www")
  })
}
ui <- fluidPage(
      fileInput("uploaded_file", "Upload", multiple = FALSE)
)
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: From `?file.copy` the following arguments may be useful: `overwrite` - should existing files be overwritten? `to` - file name or path, you can construct a new name with `paste0` or `sprintf`

Comment: @Mako212 I am unable to use it in code because my above ui.R is in folder Shiny while images are in "www" folder. Full path is: 
"C:\Users\Tayyab Salman\Documents\R\win-library\3.4\shiny\www"
Can you please help that that how can I implement this in code?